# unexcepted end of stream on Connection

Tags: java, android, database, httpurlconnection

I am doing a Android app and trying to input a new data into the student database, the connection which is HttpURLConnection is ok. I got a problem which says: java.io.IOException: unexcepted end of stream on Connection {....(here is my host address}.

I think the main problem is the conn.getOutputStream(), and I have check that the stream is not closed.

```
public static void createUser(Student user){
    //initialise
    URL url = null;
    HttpURLConnection conn = null;
    final String methodPath="/friendfinder.student/";
    try {
        Gson gson =new Gson();
        String stringUserJson=gson.toJson(user);
        url = new URL(BASE_URI + methodPath);
//open the connection
        conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
//set the timeout
        conn.setReadTimeout(10000);
        conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
//set the connection method to POST
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        //set the output to true
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
//set length of the data you want to send
        conn.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(stringUserJson.getBytes().length);
//add HTTP headers
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
//Send the POST out
        PrintWriter out= new PrintWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
        out.print(stringUserJson);
        out.close();
        Log.i("error",new Integer(conn.getResponseCode()).toString());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        conn.disconnect();
    }
}
```

Would someone take a look at my code and give me a suggestion please?

Comment: Which line throws the error? Without this information it may be difficult to help you...

Comment: I'm so sorry I forgot to mention that the error occurs at the e.printStackTrace(), the e shows the java.io.IOException: unexcepted end of stream on Connection {....(here is my host address}.

Comment: Below the exception there should be a stack trace. This information is important for us to help you.